# Mongodb Index behavior different in PROD and Testing environment

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have 2 dedicated Mongo clusters which have the same exact Model, Indexes and we query both envs the same way but the result is different.

user.model.js

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: ObjectId,
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'admin'],
    required: true,
  },
  score: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  deactivated: { type: Date },
});

schema.index(
  { deactivated: 1, role: 1, score: -1 },
  { name: 'search_index', collation: { locale: 'en', strength: 2 } }
);
```

I noticed that one of our common queries was causing issues on the PROD environment.
The query looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('users')
    .find({deactivated: null, role: 'user'})
    .sort({score: -1})
    .limit(10)
    .collation({locale: 'en', strength: 2})
```

On the Testing Environment the query runs as expected fully utilizing the index. (has ~80K records total, 1300 deactivated)
[image]

But in our PROD env the query, seems to be using only the first part of the compound index. (has ~50K records total, ~20K records deactivated)
The executionStats looks like:
[image]

As we can see it is using at least the first part of the index to only search in non-deactivated records, but the SORT is in memory.

This is a legacy application so the first thing I did was ensure that the types of the indexed fields are following the schema in all the records.
I wonder if it could be the "role" collation somehow?

Any hint or clue will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please upload the actual _text_ of both of the explain plans (ideally `"allPlansExecution" verbosity) for us to review? Perhaps use pastebin.com. There is too much truncated here by the screenshot for us to review. There's no way, for example, to confirm how the indexes are being used or why the plan selection is different between the environments. As an arbitrary guess, does the production index have the same collation?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying you already helped me a lot.
Here are the 2 allPlansExecution explains.
PROD: https://pastebin.com/6fX4j223
TESTING: https://pastebin.com/Z9maDdh7
Basically while I was querying the information you asked for I realized that
"isMultiKey" : true
Is marked on the PROD environment and the "score" field is the one with the issue as you can see. 
But when I run:
db.getCollection('users').count({followers: {$type: 'array'} }) the result is 0
Any idea what I need to do?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing the plans. It is a combination of a few things (including the multikeyness of the production index) that is causing the problem.

There are a few ways to potentially solve this, let's start with the obvious question. Is `score` supposed to be an array?

The schema suggests not. With MongoDB, an index becomes multikey once a single document is inserted that has an array (even empty) for a key in the index. There is no way to way to "undo" this change apart from rebuilding the index. If the field is not supposed to contain an array, then I would suggest fixing any documents that contain the incorrect data and then rebuilding the index. As this is production, you may want to build a temporary index to reduce the impact to the application while the original index is dropped and recreated. You may also want to look into schema validation to help prevent incorrect data from getting inserted in the future.

If `score` *can* be an array, then we'll need to take a different approach. We can see in the UAT plan that a `SORT_MERGE` is used. The only reason that stage is required is because `{"deactivated" : null}` seems to have an additional index bound looking for `undefined`. That may be some internal implementation quirk as [that BSON type appears to be deprecated](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/). So updating the data to have an explicit `false` value for this field and using that check in the query predicate (rather than a check for `null`) will remove the need to split the plan out with a `SORT_MERGE` and will probably allow the multikey index to provide the sort:

```
    winningPlan: {
      stage: 'LIMIT',
      limitAmount: 10,
      inputStage: {
        stage: 'FETCH',
        inputStage: {
          stage: 'IXSCAN',
          keyPattern: { deactivated: 1, role: 1, score: -1 },
          indexName: 'search_index',
          collation: {
            locale: 'en',
            caseLevel: false,
            caseFirst: 'off',
            strength: 2,
            numericOrdering: false,
            alternate: 'non-ignorable',
            maxVariable: 'punct',
            normalization: false,
            backwards: false,
            version: '57.1'
          },
          isMultiKey: true,
          multiKeyPaths: { deactivated: [], role: [], score: [ 'score' ] },
          isUnique: false,
          isSparse: false,
          isPartial: false,
          indexVersion: 2,
          direction: 'forward',
          indexBounds: {
            deactivated: [ '[false, false]' ],
            role: [
              '[CollationKey(0x514d314b0108), CollationKey(0x514d314b0108)]'
            ],
            score: [ '[MaxKey, MinKey]' ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```